# How to limit a container's width to X when it contains a wider (>X) image?

Tags: css

I need my `div` element to be as wide as the screen even when its child image element is wider than that. Is that possible? I tried `overflow: hidden` on the div to no avail.

```
<div>
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Set the max width to 99% of the viewport width - max-width: 99vw;

Comment: Set your div to `max-width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` too.

Comment: Works, thanks! Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your html so this answer might not be the only/best way.

Having `overflow: hidden` merely makes your div hide whatever content "spills out" of its box. However, by default a div will have it's `width: auto`, and that makes the div stretch to accommodate whatever children element it holds.

Simply by adding `max-width: 100%`, you force the div to stop growing beyond the width of its parent. This way the div will try to stretch for the sake of its children, but not far enough as to go against its parent.

In your case the image is trying to stretch the div more than it should, so `overflow: hidden` comes into play and hides the part of the image that surpasses the div's width.

Comment: Nice wording with "for the sake of its children, but not far enough as to go against its parent" :)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file

```
img {
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

div img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600" />
</div>
```

Comment: `background-image: cover;` confuses me... why is that there?

Comment: oops, typo. I'll fix it. Cover tells the browser to make sure the image always covers the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges.